# ViewPager not bouncing to half screen

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-view

I am trying to achieve is user would open to first page of the view pager, and the view pager would bounce like spring to half of the second page and bounce back to the fist page indicating that there are more pages to scroll to. In my code it just shows next half page. It is working fine. But animation of bouncing is not working.

```
private int animFactor;
private ValueAnimator animator = new ValueAnimator();
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
// private Animation animation1=  new TranslateAnimation()

private void animateViewPager(final ViewPager pager, final int offset, final int delay) {

    if (!animator.isRunning()) {
        animator.removeAllUpdateListeners();
        animator.removeAllListeners();
        //Set animation
        animator.setIntValues(0, -offset);
        animator.setDuration(delay);
        animator.setRepeatCount(1);
        animator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
        animator.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                Integer value = animFactor * (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                if (!pager.isFakeDragging()) {
                    pager.beginFakeDrag();
                }
                pager.fakeDragBy(value);
            }
        });
        animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                animFactor = 1;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                pager.endFakeDrag();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                animFactor = -1;
            }
        });
        set.play(animator);
        set.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: i got solution we can do this using Animation class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   private void animateViewPager(final ViewPager pager, final int offset, final int delay) {
    if (!animator.isRunning()) {
        animator.removeAllUpdateListeners();
        animator.removeAllListeners();
        //Set animation
        animator.setIntValues(0, -offset);
        animator.setDuration(delay);
        animator.setRepeatCount(1);
        animator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
        animator.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                Integer value = animFactor * (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                if (!pager.isFakeDragging()) {
                    pager.beginFakeDrag();
                }
                pager.fakeDragBy(value);
            }
        });
        animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                animFactor = 1;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                pager.endFakeDrag();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                animFactor = -1;
            }
        });
        set.play(animator);
        set.start();
    }
}
```

and call this method using this way

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if (hasFocus) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (articleDetailPager.getCurrentItem() >= 0) {
                    Context context = ArticleDetailActivity.this;
                    String filename = "Init";
                    SharedPreferences stats;
                    stats = context.getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
                    int appOpen = stats.getInt("appOpen", 0);

                    if (appOpen == 0) {
                        animateViewPager(articleDetailPager, 20, 300);

                        appOpen += 1;
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = stats.edit();
                        editor.putInt("appOpen", appOpen);
                        editor.commit();
                    }
                }

            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);

    }
}
```